# JpaRepository nativeQuery - table does not exists

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

when trying to perform an update on table using JpaRepository and @Query annotation I receive an error "Table not exists" and:

```
has thrown exception:org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could n
ot execute statement
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute s
tatement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException
: could not execute statement
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
        ... 154 common frames omitted
```

My Query:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE T_MY_TABLE SET VISIBLE_FLAG = 0 "
        + "WHERE ID = :myId ")
int updateMyTab(@Param("myId") Long myId);
```

When using JpaRepository.save method to update the table, it executes normally without any problems.

Also, I have SELECT nativeQueries, which works. Only the updates does not.

On table there is:
- created synonym for the schema
- grants for select, insert, update, delete for the schema

Table DOES exists, the update, if executed directly on DB and on any schema/user it works without any problems and updates rows

Comment: Activate the hibernate query log and post here the generated query.

Comment: have you tried specifying schema in the query like `UPDATE SCHEMA.T_MY_TABLE SET VISIBLE_FLAG = 0`

Comment: @Maciej eM: were you able to fix this issue. I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not remember how it was fixed in the end. Changed projects 3 times over that time, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue - problem was in database object naming. I used upper-case in object naming while tables names were case sensitive. I had to change:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE T_MY_TABLE SET VISIBLE_FLAG = 0 "
        + "WHERE ID = :myId ")
int updateMyTab(@Param("myId") Long myId);
```

to:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE "\t_my_table"\ SET VISIBLE_FLAG = 0 "
        + "WHERE ID = :myId ")
int updateMyTab(@Param("myId") Long myId);
```